# How to get Packages.com.lombardisoftware.client.persistence in WebSphere 8.5?

Tags: websphere, package, business-process-management

As I am new to Websphere 8.5 and I want to get access to this class

```
var c = new Packages.com.lombardisoftware.client.persistence.TWClassFactory.getInstance(myObject);
```

when I run my program it throw the exception:

> Runtime error in script ("Process: 'Test' ProcessItem: 'get schema' Type: 'ITEM'" 2:0).Can't find method 
>   com.lombardisoftware.client.persistence.common.AbstractVersionedPOFactory.findByName(string)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

All com.lombardisoftware.client.* classes and methods are undocumented APIs that are specifically prohibited from use.

I'm not sure why you having problems, but you should never be touching these internal classes anyway: they could change or break without any notice.